# How to include tab bar in main home controller programatically

Tags: swift, xcode

I am doing a project for fun, I have created a tab bar but unfortunately it pushes a new view and I am trying to implement it in my home controller. Can someone explain or show me how to make the tab bar appear in my home controller. Thank you.

Here is the home controller

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SideMenu
import GoogleSignIn


class HomeController: UIViewController {

    //Properties
    var delegate: HomeMenuControllerDelegate?
    var welcomeLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.alpha = 0
        return label
    }()
    //Map Button
//    let gotoMap: UIButton = {
//        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
//        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Image-1").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
//        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleShowMap), for: .touchUpInside)
//        return button
//    }()
    //Map Change View
//    @objc func handleShowMap() {
//        navigationController?.pushViewController(MapController(), animated: true)
//    }

    //Init

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        authenticateUserAndConfigureView()
        let newViewController = TabBarController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)



    }



    //Selectors
    @objc func handleShowSideBar() {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(MenuController(), animated: true)
    }

    @objc func handleShowTabBar() {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(TabBarController(), animated: true)
    }



    @objc func handleSignOut() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Are you sure you want to sign out?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Out", style: .destructive, handler: { (_) in
            self.signOut()
        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func handleMenuToggle() {
        delegate?.handleMenuToggle(forMenuOption: nil)
    }

    @objc func handleTabBar() {
        let handleTabBar = TabBarController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(handleTabBar, animated: true)
        self.present(handleTabBar, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //API

    func loadUserData() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let username = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
            self.welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome, \(username)"

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.welcomeLabel.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }

    func signOut() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController())
            navController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
            self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to sign out with error..", error)
        }
    }

    func authenticateUserAndConfigureView() {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController())
                navController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
                self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            configureViewComponents()
            loadUserData()
        }
    }


    //Helper Functions

    func configureViewComponents() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.mainPurple()

        navigationItem.title = "Artify"

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "baseline_clear_white_36pt_3x"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSignOut))
       navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_menu_white_3x"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleShowSideBar))

        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "baseline_arrow_back_white_24dp"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleShowTabBar))

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.mainPurple()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.mainPurple()

        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.mainPurple()

        view.addSubview(welcomeLabel)
        welcomeLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        welcomeLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        //Map Icon

//        view.addSubview(gotoMap)
//        gotoMap.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 210, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
//        gotoMap.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    }

}
```

Here is the tab bar controller

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController:UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Create Tab one
        let Map = MapController()
        let MapItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Map", image: UIImage(named: "Image-7"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "Image-7"))

        Map.tabBarItem = MapItem


        // Create Tab two
        let Trending = TrendingController()
        let TrendingBarItem2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Trending", image: UIImage(named: "profile_grey.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "profile_grey.png"))

        Trending.tabBarItem = TrendingBarItem2

        let RecentlySold = RecentlySoldController()
        let RecentlySold3 = UITabBarItem(title: "Recently Sold", image: UIImage(named: "profile_grey.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "profile_grey.png"))

        RecentlySold.tabBarItem = RecentlySold3


        self.viewControllers = [Trending, RecentlySold, Map]
    }


    // UITabBarControllerDelegate method
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
       // print("Selected \(viewController.title!)")
    }
}
```

The main result of what I am trying to accomplish is that when I am on the home page the tab bar will display also.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that code does not stop. You are saying:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    authenticateUserAndConfigureView()
    let newViewController = TabBarController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
}
```

That doesn't mean "do `authenticateUserAndConfigureView` and wait". The code does not wait. It just rushes right on and pushes the tab bar controller. If you want the user ever to see your HomeController, delete those last two lines.

The usual thing, however, would be to have the tab bar *be* the home controller. That way it is the first thing the user sees. You could then present the authentication view in front of that.

Or, you could choose (in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`) to make the first thing the user sees be the HomeController *or* the tab bar controller, depending on whether authentication has taken place.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not to sure if I understand